# Shopping Tax Refund for Working Holiday Visa in Tokyo?

Tags: taxes, working-visas, japan

I know that as a tourist, some department store will do tax refund for foreigners when you show them your passport.

But this time I will be going as with a Working Holiday Visa, not visitor visa.

Will I still be eligible to get the tax refund for foreigners?

Answer (score 2):

As per the current tax free shopping regulations, visitors with a temporary stay status are eligible for tax-free shopping.

- Japanese citizens are not eligible.
- Not eligible if you are working in Japan.
- Not eligible if staying in Japan more than six months.

If you have a working holiday visa, I imagine you are working in Japan and are therefore ineligible to receive this tax refund.

For full information on tax free shopping in Japan you can check out [enjoy.taxfree.jp](http://enjoy.taxfree.jp/)

Answer (score 1):

No, tax-free shopping is only available to foreign citizens whose status of residence is "temporary visitor". Your status will not be "temporary visitor" (it will probably be "designated activities").